# Split a dataframe and sum [pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe (dummy data):

```
            score   GDP
country     
Bangladesh  6      12
Bolivia     4      10
Nigeria     3      9
Pakistan    2      3
Ghana       1      3
India       1      3
Algeria     1      3
```

And I want to split it into two groups based on GDP and sum the score of each group. On the condition of GDP being less than 9:

```
           sum_score
country     
rich       13      
poor        5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to make your `rich` and `poor` categories, then `groupby` that category and get the sum:

```
df['country_cat'] = np.where(df.GDP < 9, 'poor', 'rich')
df.groupby('country_cat')['score'].sum()

country_cat
poor     5
rich    13
```

You can also do the same in one step, by not creating the extra column for the category (but IMO the code becomes less readable):

```
df.groupby(np.where(df.GDP < 9, 'poor', 'rich'))['score'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate by boolean mask and last only rename index:

```
a = df.groupby(df.GDP < 9)['score'].sum().rename({True:'rich', False:'poor'})
print (a)
GDP
poor    13
rich     5
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Last for one column `DataFrame` add [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = a.to_frame('sum_score')
print (df)
      sum_score
GDP            
poor         13
rich          5
```